# Proxy for requests with grunt only works with HTTP (and not HTTPS)

Tags: proxy, gruntjs, sapui5

Right now our datasources are configured in our `manifest.json` like this (which causes CORS errors btw):

```
"dataSources": {
    "contractsRemote": {
        "uri": "https://myCompany:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TEST_SRV/",
        "type": "OData",

    },
    "userInfoRemote": {
        "uri": "https://myCompany:8443/sap/bc/ui2/start_up",
        "type": "JSON"
    }
}
```

If we deploy our application (upload it via `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD`) we have to change the URIs to this

```
"dataSources": {
    "contractsRemote": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TEST_SRV/",
        "type": "OData",

    },
    "userInfoRemote": {
        "uri": "/sap/bc/ui2/start_up",
        "type": "JSON"
    }
}
```

It would be much easier if we just used the relative URI (from second snippet) in our local dev environment. So, to solve both the CORS and the URI issue, I wanted to setup a grunt task (warning, I've never done that before) that proxies the relative requests to `https://myCompany:8443/path`.

I took the example `Gruntfile.js` from some of the SAP github repos and added some lines for a proxy, and it works, but only via *HTTP*. If I change the proxy port to `8443` and set https to `true`, I get the following error

```
> Proxy error: ECONNRESET
```

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        dir: {
            webapp: 'webapp',
            dist: 'dist',
            bower_components: 'bower_components'
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 8000,
                base: 'public',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                middleware: function(connect, options, defaultMiddleware) {
                    var proxy = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
                    return [
                        proxy
                    ].concat(defaultMiddleware);
                }
            },
            proxies: [{
                context: '/sap',
                host: 'myCompany',
                port: 8443,
                https: true
            }],
            src: {},
            dist: {}
        },
        openui5_connect: {
            options: {
                resources: [
                    '<%= dir.bower_components %>/openui5-sap.ui.core/resources',
                    '<%= dir.bower_components %>/openui5-sap.m/resources',
                    '<%= dir.bower_components %>/openui5-themelib_sap_bluecrystal/resources'
                ]
            },
            src: {
                options: {
                    appresources: '<%= dir.webapp %>'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    appresources: '<%= dir.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },
        openui5_preload: {
            component: {
                options: {
                    resources: {
                        cwd: '<%= dir.webapp %>',
                        prefix: 'todo'
                    },
                    dest: '<%= dir.dist %>'
                },
                components: true
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: '<%= dir.dist %>/'
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= dir.webapp %>',
                    src: [
                        '**',
                        '!test/**'
                    ],
                    dest: '<%= dir.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        eslint: {
            webapp: ['<%= dir.webapp %>']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-openui5');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-eslint');

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {
        grunt.task.run([
            'configureProxies',
            'openui5_connect:' + (target || 'src') + ':keepalive'
        ]);
    });
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['eslint']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['openui5_preload', 'copy']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        //'lint',
        'clean',
        'build',
        'serve:dist'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

First, the localhost had to be served via https as well to access a https API.
Second, the proxy needed the right protocol (`https:`) but at the same time https had to be set to `false`. I guess for reasons.

```
connect: {
    options: {
        base: 'public',
        port: '443',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        protocol: 'https',
        open: true,
        livereload: true,
        middleware: function (connect, options, defaultMiddleware) {
            var proxy = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
            return [
                proxy
            ].concat(defaultMiddleware);
        }
    },
    proxies: [
        {
            context: '/sap',
            host: 'mySapHost',
            port: '443',
            https: false,
            protocol: 'https:'
        }
    ],
},
```

Comment: protocol: 'https:' is only thing what worked, 
whichi is undocumented option

Comment: @ShadabUmer grunt (and gulp) is considered dead now :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Probably you’re already using grunt to serve your local frontend code. Everything is fine, but if you’re developing your backend with something different than JavaScript (Being a Java developer I heard that might happen), you will have problems accessing this backend while running grunt server.
```

With grunt-connect-proxy there exists a grunt module to help you out. It basically delegates requests that match a given URL to a different backend of your choice. Unfortunately I found it rather difficult to configure, if you are unaware of the connect middleware concept.

Basically you just need to add two things to your Gruntfile.js file:

Firstly add the connect server configuration to your config JSON inside of grunt.initConfig. This example delegates all requests to http://localhost:8000/services to http://localhost:8090/services – keep in mind the grunt server is running on port 8000 and the backend on port 8090:

Comment: Pls check my edit, I added my second version of a gruntfile that still doesn't work